What is extension of an isometry?
I am reading Lorentzian geometry. I found  the following definition.
Definition: A Lorentzian manifold $M$ has maximal isometry group if the action of $\text{Isom(M)}$ is transitive and, for every point $x \in M$, every linear isometry $L ∶ T_x M \rightarrow  T_xM$ extends to an isometry of $M$.
Now I am confused about what does one mean by extension of linear isometry to an isometry of $M$?
Can anyone please help me?

"The linear isometry $L:T_{x}M \to T_{x}M$ extends to $M$" means "There exists an isometry $\phi_{L}:M \to M$ such that $D(\phi_{L})(x) = L$."
This is a Lorentzian version of isotropy.
